# Read only inputs in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, select, input, angularjs

I have some problem with readonly inputs on agularjs. I have some select which changes readonly inputs values by script. But when I try to output those values by ng-model in the table as {{ng-model}} it doesn't show.

```
<select name="well" onChange="Update(this.value)" ng-model="well" required>
<option value="Well-01">Well-01</option>
<option value="Well-02">Well-02</option>
<option value="Well-03">Well-03</option>
</select>
<label>Region:</label>
<input type="text" name="region" value="South" ng-model="region" disabled>
<label>State:</label>
<input type="text" name="state" value="Oklahoma" ng-model="state"  disabled>
<label>Field Office:</label>
<input type="text" name="office" value="Ringwood" ng-model="office" disabled>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NKyps/7/

It show {{well}} when I change it but doesn't show inputs. 
Thanks for help.
PS: also if someone knows how to use default option (for example: well-01) so inputs will be filled when document is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is those attriboutes aren't binding in some model. When you use {{variable}} angular expect this are binding with some model.

I added as scope model in your tags:

```
<form ng-controller="Sarapastrule" name="form">
</form>
```

Check in : http://jsfiddle.net/NKyps/9/

Answer (score 0):

You are operating outside of angular and doing custom DOM manipulation, which is the opposite of what angular.js is designed for.  I have an [updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/72wGt/1/).

Use a controller with a scope to define the values of your model.

```
function ExampleController($scope) {

    $scope.Update = function () {
        if ($scope.well == "Well-01") {
            $scope.region = 'South';
            $scope.state = 'Oklahoma';
            $scope.office = 'Ringwood';
        }

        if ($scope.well == "Well-02") {
            $scope.region = 'North';
            $scope.state = 'Montana';
            $scope.office = 'Sidney';
        }

        if ($scope.well == "Well-03") {
            $scope.region = 'North';
            $scope.state = 'North Dakota';
            $scope.office = 'Tioga';
        }
    }

    $scope.well = 'Well-01';
    $scope.Update();
}
```

The main problem with your design is that you are attempting to maintain 2 congruent models, one in javascript and the other in the dom.  Angular.js excels at handling the dom manipulation for you so you only have to worry about updating your model.  Instead of trying to manually update the dom, just build out the view so that it generates itself from a model, and then only allow yourself to update the javascript model ($scope variable).

Comment: I don't think your link is correct. Seems it points to the old jsFiddle. As I said in my answer i would use a watch instead of an update method. The watch is called during initialization by AngularJS once so that the model gets initialized. Afterwards it is called when the well model is changed.

Comment: Ok, I see. You use the the ng-change directive instead of a $watch probably following the initial pattern of the onChange event handler.

Comment: I agree that a watch is better.  So would be using a better form of the controller and a better data model, but for someone who is clearly just getting started with it, I like to stick to patterns used in the docs because I think it makes it easier to relate.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Bart said, you are missing the basic concepts of AngularJS and should read the AngularJS tutorial at http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial.

AngularJS is about two way data-binding. So it takes care of updating the DOM while you as a developer are only updating the model. Access to the value properties of input fields as you have done it is not the way you use Angular.

I have updated your jsFiddle to a working version but nevertheless you should read the tutorial to get the concepts behind AngularJS.

http://jsfiddle.net/BnqZS/1/

As you can see you need a controller first which handles business logic. In the controller watch and update the model. So instead of

```
if (choice == "Well-01") {
    region.value = 'South';
    state.value = 'Oklahoma';
    office.value = 'Ringwood';
}
```

You should actually set a watch on the model you have bound to the option input and write:

```
$scope.$watch('well', function(choice) {
  if (choice == "Well-01") {
        $scope.region = 'South';
        $scope.state = 'Oklahoma';
        $scope.office = 'Ringwood';
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for advice, I'll take note of this.